# Proper way to stop a thread from a destructor

Tags: c++, destructor

I have a class that has a `Start` method to start a thread that executes the virtual `ThreadFunction` at a predefined interval. The `Stop` method sets an event and waits until the the thread terminates (by a `WaitForSingleObject` on the thread handle).

In the destructor of `MyThread`, I call the `Stop` method. So whenever I delete the instance, I'm sure the thread is stopped before the delete returns.

```
class MyThread
{
    void Start();
    void Stop();
    ~MyThread() { Stop(); }
    virtual VOID ThreadFunction() { }
};
```

Next I have a class that derives from `MyThread`:

```
class A : MyThread
{
    virtual VOID ThreadFunction()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
            TestFunction();
    }

    void TestFunction() { // Do something }
};
```

Consider this code:

```
A a = new A();
a->Start();
delete a;
```

The problem is that `delete a` will first call the destructor of `A` before it will call the destructor of `MyThread` right? So if the thread was executing the `for-loop` in the `ThreadFunction`, the `Stop` method will be called after `a` has been destructed. This can lead to an access violation, when `ThreadFunction` calls `TestFunction` on a destructed instance.

A solution would be to add a destructor to `class A` that calls the `Stop` method, like this:

```
class A : MyThread
{
    ~A()
   {
       Stop();
   }
}
```

But because I have a more complex class hiërarchy, that involves multiple inherited classes, this would mean I have to call the `Stop` method in each destructor, which would result in the Stop method being called plenty of times for only one instance that needs to be deleted.

Is there any other way to tackle this problem?

Comment: Explicitly call a cleanup function (stop in your case) before deleting the class, not convenient but thats how I would do it. I always try to put as little code as possible in the destructor, just for the reason you described how destructors work

Comment: This is probably a reason most people don't bother with Java-like thread classes. This class has more than one responsibility: it is managing the thread's lifetime *and* the code it executes. Separate the two concerns and everything will become easy.

Comment: Actually, the destructor of `MyThread won't be called at all since it's not `virtual`. If it was, then it would work fine since while the destructors are called the actual memory haven't been released yet, so e.g. `this` still works even when the `A` destructor has been called. You have to be carefull though, since member variables may have been free'd and destructed so access to them may cause problems after the `A` destructor has been called.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: destructors are called in the order I described in my question, at least that is what my debugger tells me while stepping through the code. And the destructors aren't defined as `virtual`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Rolle and R. Martinho Fernandes suggested, I needed to separate the two concerns.

`class MyThread` should not start or stop itself as its responsibility should be limited to the code it executes and not to the lifetime of the thread.

So the solution was to stop the thread from an other class (the same class that started the thread) which is responsible for the lifetime of the thread.

Answer (score 1):

Your destructor in MyThread should be defined as 'virtual'.

```
class A{
public:
    A(){cout<<"A"<<endl;}
    virtual ~A(){cout<<"~A"<<endl;}
};

class B : public A{ 
public:
    B(){cout<<"B"<<endl;}
    ~B(){cout<<"~B"<<endl;}
};

int main(){
    A* b = new B();
    cout<<"do something"<<endl;
    delete b;
    b = NULL;
    return 0;
}
```

The result is:
A
B
do something
~B
~A

and when it doesn't use virtual, The result is:
A
B
do something
~A

Comment: It will not help with the issue OP asks for though, that is that data members may have been deleted

Comment: I stepped through the code, and I first get in the destructor of `A` and finally in the destructor of `MyThread`. And they aren't defined as `virtual`. So what you say doesn't look like what I'm seeing.

Comment: The destructor being virtual only matters if you destroy it through a pointer to `MyThread`. Since the code is using a pointer to `A`, there's no problem there (you should still make it virtual to avoid that issue).

Comment: Right advice, wrong reason. Having a non-virtual destructor is a problem if delete is invoked on a base class pointer.

Comment: @aasa: I see that you have modified your answer. I agree with you that I would need a virtual destructor if I did this: `delete (MyThread *)a;`, but I'm not doing that and this really isn't going to solve my problem here :) Anyway thanks for your effort!

Comment: Oh, sorry, I misunderstood your question. I think maybe you can try to use MyThread as a member of A, and put A's pointer as a para into the thread function.

Comment: @aasa: that's in fact a good idea. To bad I can't change the interface in such a dramatic way, so for now I'll followed the comment of Rolle. There is always a class where I call `Start` on a newly constructed instance. In these classes I'm now adding a call to the `Stop` method before actually deleting the instance. As a last step I will remove the `Stop()` call from the `MyThread` destructor.